# Extracting the related head of each word from .conll-x files

Tags: python, nlp

I am working on .conll files of dependency parsed sentences. I would like to know how to extract the related head of each word based on its id number shown in column 6 of .conll-x files.

Here is a part of my code where I read .conll file and extract some columns.

```
result=[[]]
with open('S008_T1_M_Pre_NNAS_W_C_Fre.conllx',"r") as input:
for line in input:

if not line.startswith("#"): 
#print(line)

if line.strip() =="":

result.append([])
else:
result[-1].append(line.split())

to remove empty lists from the list
result = list(filter(lambda x: x, result))

#print(result)


word_head_rel = []
res = []
for nested_lists in result:
for lists in nested_lists:
id_item = lists[0]
word = lists[1]
head_id = lists[6]
dep_rel = lists[7]

word_head_rel.append([id_item, word, dep_rel, head_id])
print(word_head_rel)
```

I could extract and create a nested list of the id of the word, the form of the word itself, its dependency relation, and the id of its head (index of syntactic parent) respectively as shown in the nested list below:

```
[['1', 'جزى', 'SBJ', '3'], ['2', '+هم', 'IDF', '1'], ['3','الله', '---', '0'], 
['4',
```

'خيرا', 'MOD', '3'], ['5', '.', 'MOD', '3']]

What I want is to replace the last item (the id of the head of the word with the actual form of the head word) the desired output is shown below:

```
[['1', 'جزى', 'SBJ', 'خيرا'],  
['2', '+هم', 'IDF', 'جزى'],
['3', 'الله', '---', 'الله'],
['4', 'خيرا', 'MOD', 'الله'],
['5', '.', 'MOD', 'الله']]
```

Note: I want to create this new list for each sentence. One .conll file might have more than 4 sentences which means a list of 4 nested lists.

Comment: Please fix the indentation.